# geometric distribution on interval

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is it possible to define a geometric distributed variable with parameter p on an interval $[a,b]$, such that

$$ c \cdot \sum_{j=a}^b (1-p)^j p=1$$
with a scale factor $c$.
Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to define it, although the name "geometric distribution" may be confusing, since it commonly refers to a [distribution on a different domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). "Geometric distribution on a bounded domain" seems correct – maybe it's used somewhere. You might also call it a "geometrically varying" distribution if you like, since subsequent probabilities are in a fixed ratio, just like for the ordinary geometric distribution.

Such a distribution can in fact be rewritten in the form $\mathrm{p}(i \vert \lambda) = \frac{1}{Z(\lambda)} \exp(\lambda\ i)$ with
$$Z(\lambda):=\frac{\exp[(b+1/2)\ \lambda]-\exp[(a-1/2)\ \lambda]}{\exp(\lambda/2)-\exp(-\lambda/2)}\ ,$$
obtainable using the expression of the partial sum of a geometric series.
Note that the parameter $\lambda \equiv \ln(1-p)$ is determined by the mean of the distribution, and vice versa. I don't think there's an analytic expression giving $\lambda$ as a function of the mean, but I'm not sure to be honest.

Also, the mean (ie, first moment) is a sufficient statistics because of the special exponential form (see ref. below). So this is also a maximum-entropy distribution with the mean (ie, first moment) as constraint.

I think that the parameter $p$ in your expression ceases to have the specific meaning it has for the ordinary [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Whether this distribution is reasonable or not depends completely on the specific problem you're applying it to – for example, can you consider the mean to be a sufficient statistics, in your problem?

See eg Bernardo, Smith: [*Bayesian Theory*](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470316870) (Wiley 2000), § 4.5.

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Comment: That was exatly what I am looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to add some context about why you need this distribution, in your question. It may be useful for other users :)

Comment: But in the end we have an geometric distribution which is only defined on an interval. Is it wrong to call it that way?

Comment: "geometric distribution" is an established name for a different distribution, so you may cause confusion. This can simply be called a maximum-entropy distribution, or a geometrically varying distribution if you like, since the subsequent probabilities are in a fixed ratio, just like for the ordinary geometric distribution.

Comment: Ok that would be better. Maybe scaled geoemtric distribution could also be reasonable?

Comment: I don't consider it as "scaled", because the change of scale is enforced by the normalization, it isn't a free choice. But this is my subjective opinion. I suppose people will have different opinions on whether it's a reasonable name or not.

Comment: ...I mean, "geometric distribution on a bounded domain" for me is a fine name. But consider that there are always hurried readers that may skip over the "on a bounded domain" part and thus misunderstand you. You're the best judge for your specific circumstances.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thank you very much for your explanation:)

Comment: I think if I describe my probem in the right way, I can somehow refer to the geometrix distribution since it has this specific form.

Comment: Indeed, please do add some context about your problem in your question, that's always useful for other people with similar questions.

Comment: I think that would need a lot of explanation. But I will try it.